# Mensaje de error al no encontrar imagen en ruta definida

Tags: vba

Tengo un codigo de VBA el cual me inserta imagenes en una diapositiva, quiero que cuando ejecute el codigo y no encuentre la imagen en la ruta definida me arroje un mensaje el cual diga "imagen x" no se encuentra disponible, tambien como puedo hacer para que me acepte imagenes en png y jpg sin tener que indicarlo en el codigo?

```
Sub ajustar2()


Dim imagen1 As Slide, pic As Shape


'imagenes diapo 2'

'Area 1'



Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
Set pic = imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="F:\trabajo\pryecto2\mensual.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=15, Top:=84, Width:=244, Height:=142)
    
    
    
With pic
    
.Line.Weight = 1
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Seleccionar el color
.ZOrder (msoSendToBack)

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza esto:

Declara la imagen

```
Dim f_imagen as string
```

Escribes la ruta a la imagen

```
f_imagen = "F:\trabajo\pryecto2\mensual.png"
```

Y con esto compruebas si la ruta de la imagen contiene la imagen:

```
If Len(Dir(Filename)) = 0 then msgbox "La imagen " & f_imagen & " no se encuentra disponible."
```

Por último,en Set pic, llamas a la imagen desde su nombre de variable:

```
Set pic = imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=f_imagen , LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=15, Top:=84, Width:=244, Height:=142)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero si quiero que acepte ambos formatos jpg y png?

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres decir. Si la imagen puede ser jpg o png lo que tienes es que hacer un if y comprobar con Len(Dir....) si tu imagen es mensual.jpg o mensual.png. Si Len(Dir....) es distinto de cero sabrás cual es la imagen correcta. ¿Es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: hola, lo intente pero no funciona.

Comment: Hola @Daxtrox, actualiza tu hilo principal y añade el código que has modificado y que no te funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si tengo 2 imágenes cómo puedo hacer para que verifique la primera y luego pase a la segunda?

Comment: ?Qué es para ti "verificar"? ¿Comprobar si existe o no la imagen? Si son solo dos imágenes a comprobar puedes crear dos variables: Dim img_jpgf as string y Dim img_png as string. Luego las defines como te he puesto en mi respuesta: img_png = "ruta_de_la_imagen_png" y img_jpg = "ruta_img_jpg" Y por último con un If realizas la comprobación de ambas: If Len(dir(img_png)) > 0 then .... lo que sea que quieras hacer si existe el png.

Y otro IF haciendo referencia a img_jpg.